# What are common Swedish attitudes towards sexual relationships with large age gaps?

Tags: sweden, culture, socializing

Because the age of consent in Sweden is 15, I assumed that it reflected a “sexually liberal” general culture in which there was a social consensus that it is ok for someone of at least 15 years of age to have sex with somebody else (implicitly, who may be more than just a few years older than 15).

I recently had a pretty bad social experience in which three Swedish people were all basically shocked that I said that I think that a consensual (normal, positive, healthy) sexual relationship between a 15 year old and someone in their 20s is ok, especially given that it’s legal.

All of them seemed to not merely disagree but to find this position deeply taboo, like you are a really messed up person if you think that. Two of them said that this is really a not common social attitude in Sweden, and based on their reaction, I was inclined to believe them.

That said, I found it genuinely surprising that it would be made legal by the government representatives of the voting population, despite it (possibly) being intensely socially frowned upon. I wonder if these were just the attitudes of the people I was hanging out with that night.

Is there a widespread status quo in Sweden that relationships with large age gaps, especially if one of the partners is relatively young, are morally or socially wrong, in spite of it being legal, or are there, as I originally thought, at least factions of the society who are more what I would call “sex-positive” and think that the law was made to reflect a social belief that such a thing is not inherently wrong (barring specific additional conditions like being creepy, harassment, pressure, etc.), otherwise, if it was, it would be illegal. I mean, Sweden has no issue with making things they disapprove of illegal, such as prostitution and marijuana.

As a point of reference, the recent well-received film [Call Me By Your Name](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_Me_by_Your_Name_(film)) depicts an amorous, and sexual, relationship between a 17 year old and a 24 year old, and I never heard anyone saying it depicted something morally on the verge of pedophilia, but was rather a candid, real depiction of the erotic dimension of human life.

I was really surprised how negatively my opinion was received and would like to understand if there is a social group in Sweden with whom I can have solidarity with in my views, or if being new to this culture I was oblivious to common social attitudes here regarding this topic.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Someone "in their twenties" could be almost twice the age of a fifteen year old.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether there are studies on attitudes, but there is data on established couples. In particular, the average age difference in a relationship is 2.2 years, according to [SCB](https://www.scb.se/hitta-statistik/artiklar/2022/varierande-aldersskillnader-bland-svenska-hjartan/). The age difference is generally smaller the higher the educational level of the people in the couple is. They only have sufficient data for a proper analysis of couples where the woman is aged 20-90, but the (slight) trend is that the younger the woman is, the more likely she is dating someone the same age as her. Large age gap relationships are extremely uncommon, especially with people younger than 40 or older than 80. Age gaps would be most accepted in very religious conservative circles, but there the idea of sex outside marriage would not be accepted. A man in his twenties could certainly "date" a teenage girl in, for example, some  of the insular "frikyrkliga" communities, but the expectation would be marriage as soon as she's 18, and possibly a (not legally binding) ceremony immediately.

Purely anecdotal, but many people in my circles at least (university educated middle class) are going to assume that there is some unhealthy power dynamic going on in a couple where one person is legally a child and the other person has been an adult for some years (even if the relationship is superficially consensual). "Sex positivity" does not mean being positive to everything to do with sex - as you noted, Sweden uses the Nordic model to curb prostitution, which is based on the assumption that prostitution is a form of violence against women regardless of whether there is consent involved in a particular exchange. You may be interested to know that support for the Nordic model is at [91% among women and 63% among men](https://via.tt.se/pressmeddelande/3396683/klyftan-mellan-konen-i-synen-pa-sexkop-okar-visar-ny-opinionsundersokning?publisherId=3236601&lang=sv), so a large majority of Sweden's population agrees with this reasoning, where superficial consent does not negate an unhealthy power dynamic. The basic assumption with laws are that things are legal unless they are explicitly banned. Adults having sex with teenagers being legal can therefore be interpreted as it not being seen as a major societal problem that has to be banned, rather than an active choice to allow.

And if nothing else, they are going to question what you could possibly have in common or do together with a teenager. In general you would be expected to be in a relationship with someone whose company you enjoy, and what do you, as an adult, do with a 15 year old? Pick them up from football practise and help them with their history homework? Again with reference to my social circle, there is a strong expectation to date one of your "peers", in the sense of someone you meet through friends, work, or hobby activities. There are not that many chances for an adult to naturally come across a teenager in one of those contexts unless you are their football coach (which raises concerns regarding power dynamics), and actively seeking out teenagers as an adult comes across as predatory.

Sex positivity in Sweden means that there is a great deal of acceptance for teenagers having sex, but the expectation is that they do so with other teenagers.